# Way to replicate getters/setters for public properties in a POJO

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming

We have a POJO that is auto-generated with ~60 properties. This is generated with avro 1.4, which does not include getters/setters.

A library that we use to provide simple transformations between objects requires getter/setter-like methods in order to properly work.

Is there a way to replicate getters/setters without having to manually override the POJO and create all of the getters/setters manually?

```
public class BigGeneratedPojo {
  public String firstField;
  public int secondField;
  ...
  public ComplexObject nthField;
}

public class OtherObject {
  private String reprOfFirstFieldFromOtherObject;
  private ComplexObject reprOfFirstFieldFromOtherObject;
  public String getReprOfFirstFieldFromOtherObject() { ... standard impl ... };
  public void setReprOfFirstFieldFromOtherObject() { ... standard impl ... };
}
```

the desire is to write code that looks like:

```
Mapper<BigGeneratedPojo, OtherObject> mapper = 
  MagicalMapperLibrary.mapperBuilder(BigGeneratedPojo.class, OtherObject.class)
    .from(BigGeneratedPojo::getFirstField).to(OtherObject::reprOfFirstFieldFromOtherObject)
    .build();

BigGeneratedPojo pojo = new BigGeneratedPojo();
pojo.firstField = "test";

OtherObject mappedOtherObj = mapper.map(pojo);

assertEquals(mappedOtherObj.getReprOfFirstFieldFromOtherObject(), "test");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try to generate the proxy beans dynamically, for instance, using BitBuddy: https://bytebuddy.net/

The sample below shows how to proxy a property field of a method. Note that this is only a sample, and most probably you might have to wrap it and add some dynamic using reflections, but I think it's quite an interesting option if you wish to dynamically extend code.

```
import net.bytebuddy.ByteBuddy;
import net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.FixedValue;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.MethodDelegation;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.RuntimeType;
import net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.Opcodes;
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public class M1 {

    public static class PojoBase {
        int property;
        String strProp;
    }



    public static class Intereptor {

        private final String fieldName;
        private final PojoBase pojo;
        public Intereptor(PojoBase pojo, String fieldName) {
            this.pojo = pojo;
            this.fieldName = fieldName;
        }
        @RuntimeType
        public Object intercept(@RuntimeType Object value) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {

            Field field = pojo.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.set(pojo, value);
            return value;
        }
    }



    public static void main(String... args) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException {
            PojoBase origBean = new PojoBase();
            PojoBase destBean = new PojoBase();

            origBean.property = 555666;
            origBean.strProp = "FooBar";

        DynamicType.Builder<Object> stub = new ByteBuddy()
            .subclass(Object.class);

        DynamicType.Builder.MethodDefinition.ReceiverTypeDefinition<Object> dynamic = stub.defineMethod("getProperty", Integer.TYPE, Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC).intercept(FixedValue.value(origBean.property))
                .defineMethod("setProperty", Void.TYPE, Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC).withParameters(Integer.TYPE).intercept(MethodDelegation.to(new Intereptor(destBean, "property")))
                .defineMethod("getStrProp", String.class, Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC).intercept(FixedValue.value(origBean.strProp))
                .defineMethod("setStrProp", Void.TYPE, Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC).withParameters(String.class).intercept(MethodDelegation.to(new Intereptor(destBean, "strProp")));

        Class<?> dynamicType =     dynamic.make()
                .load(M1.class.getClassLoader())
                .getLoaded();


            Object readerObject = dynamicType.newInstance();
            Object writterObject = dynamicType.newInstance();


            BeanUtils.copyProperties(readerObject, writterObject);
            System.out.println("Out property:" + destBean.property);
            System.out.println("Out strProp:" + destBean.property);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 11):

[Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) provides @Getter and @Setter annotations which can be used at class level to generate getter and setter methods automatically.

Lombok also has the capability to generate equals and hashcode methods.

Or you can use the `@Data` which is according to lombok website:

> @Data All together now: A shortcut for @ToString, @EqualsAndHashCode,
>   @Getter on all fields, @Setter on all non-final fields, and
>   @RequiredArgsConstructor!

```
@Data
public class BigGeneratedPojo {
  public String firstField;
  public int secondField;
  ...
  public ComplexObject nthField;
}
```

Comment: Lombok is easy to use and fast to setup. This is a good solution.

Comment: I think for a short-cut is the easy implementation,  will solve the problem and also give you a high readability

Answer (score 4):

Given your constraints, I'd add another code generation step. How to implement it exactly depends on your build system (Maven/Gradle/something else), but [JavaParser](https://javaparser.org/) or [Roaster](https://github.com/forge/roaster) will allow you to parse `BigGeneratedPojo.java` and create a subclass with the desired getters/setters, and the build system should automatically update it if `BigGeneratedPojo` changes.

Answer (score 1):

IDEs like Eclipse and STS provide option to add getters/setters methods. we can use those option to create setters/getters methods

Comment: The issue is not writing the actual methods. I know how to generate those quickly in intellij. The problem arises in the fact that `BigGeneratedPojo ` is a generated file, so in order to actually manipulate it I would need to subclass it and have a wrapper class w/ ~120 dummy methods (60 getters/setters) and is a nightmare to maintain.

Comment: @Anthony When you open the file in the IDE’s editor, it is irrelevant whether the file has been generated or written manually. In either case, you can add the methods with a single action. Only when you plan to re-generate the file, it won’t work. But then, having a class with 60 potentially changing properties is already a “a nightmare to maintain”.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using reflection to get the public fields from your class and create the getters and setters using your own Java program as follows. Consider the following class as an example.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Arrays;

class TestClass {

    private int value;
    private String name;
    private boolean flag;
}

public class GetterSetterGenerator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            GetterSetterGenerator gt = new GetterSetterGenerator();
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            Class<?> c = Class.forName("TestClass");
            // Getting fields of the class
            Field[] fields = c.getDeclaredFields();

            for (Field f : fields) {
                String fieldName = f.getName();
                String fieldType = f.getType().getSimpleName();

                gt.createSetter(fieldName, fieldType, sb);
                gt.createGetter(fieldName, fieldType, sb);
            }
            System.out.println("" + sb.toString());

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void createSetter(String fieldName, String fieldType, StringBuffer setter) {
        setter.append("public void").append(" set");
        setter.append(getFieldName(fieldName));
        setter.append("(" + fieldType + " " + fieldName + ") {");
        setter.append("\n\t this." + fieldName + " = " + fieldName + ";");
        setter.append("\n" + "}" + "\n");
    }

    private void createGetter(String fieldName, String fieldType, StringBuffer getter) {
        // for boolean field method starts with "is" otherwise with "get"
        getter.append("public " + fieldType).append((fieldType.equals("boolean") ? " is" : " get") + getFieldName(fieldName) + " () { ");
        getter.append("\n\treturn " + fieldName + ";");
        getter.append("\n" + "}" + "\n");
    }

    private String getFieldName(String fieldName) {
        return fieldName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + fieldName.substring(1, fieldName.length());
    }
}
```

The code is taken [from here](https://netjs.blogspot.com/2017/08/generating-getters-and-setters-using-reflection-java.html) - slightly modified to avoid unnecessary `System.out`. You can easily create a file from your `main` function and put your getters and setters there.

You can check the program by [running it here](https://www.onlinegdb.com/BJZA-nXhS) as well. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Lombok. Is is easy to use and implement. It will create getters and setter in .class file post compilation. It also keeps the code look cleaner.

```
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor
public class User implements Serializable {
 private @Id Long id;

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private int age;

public User(String firstName, String lastName, int age) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.age = age;
}
```

}